# Can't remove an Item from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

Hello guys I creating an ecommerce part of the website,could you please help me with removing element from local storage,I don't want to create multiple functions for removing each element,but still nothing works,help me please

```
let pList = document.getElementById("productList")

//Espresso

const addEspresso = () => {
  var Espresso, esp, eObj;
  Espresso = {
    name: "Espresso",
    type: "strong",
    imgSrc: "images/c7.png"
  };

  localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(Espresso));

  esp = localStorage.getItem("Espresso");
  eObj = JSON.parse(esp);

  let htmlEspresso = "";
  htmlEspresso += `
         <div class="productDiv">
         <p>${eObj.name}</p> 
         <p>${eObj.type}</p>
         <img src="${eObj.imgSrc}">
         <button class="btn-remove">REMOVE</button>
         </div>
         `

  document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML += htmlEspresso
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var btnR = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-remove");
  if (e.target.classList.contains("btn-remove")) {
    e.target.closest(".productDiv").remove();
    //localStorage.removeItem(e.target.parentElement) - This does not work,I do not understand what to do with it
  }
})
```

Comment: `"Espresso" != e.target.parentElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.parentElement will return you the DOM element not the text. You can do some parsing after it or check for you particular `p` element inside it.

Your first `p` child will hold the text `Espresso`. You can get it using .textContent. This is the key you saved in the storage.

```
localStorage.removeItem(e.target.parentElement.querySelector('p').textContent);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!It worked for me,but do you know how to add more than 1 element in localStorage?For example I wanted to add one more property for object "quantity".How do I make it append +1 to it on each click but for the product to not appear again?

Comment: You will have to getItem modify and then setItem again. That is the only way.